# Pandas Combine 2 columns from a csv and clear NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I just started using pandas library and I want to learn more about combining two or more columns from a CSV file and clearing out the NaN value.

Here, I tried to combine two columns Fruit1 and Fruit2 into Fruits and save them into a new CSV file(Test2). The problem I am facing is clearing the NaN value.

For Example:
I used Test1.csv 
Test1.csv

```
ID,Description,Fruit1,Fruit2
1,,Apple,Banana
2,,Pears,Grapes
3,,mango
4,,,pineapple
```

and combined column Fruit1 and Fruit2 to Fruits and save them into Test2.csv and got this result 
Test2.csv

```
ID,Description,Fruits
1,,"Apple, Banana"
2,,"Pears, Grapes"
3,,"mango, nan"
4,,"nan, pineapple"
```

I want to get rid of the nan values from some rows so that the Output would be something like this:
Test2.csv (Expected)

```
ID,Description,Fruits
1,,"Apple, Banana"
2,,"Pears, Grapes"
3,,"mango"
4,,"pineapple"
```

Can someone please guide me on achieving the above result?
This is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("Test1.csv")
df['Fruits'] = df['Fruit1'].astype(str) + ', ' + df['Fruit2'].astype(str)
df.drop(['Fruit1', 'Fruit2'] , axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("Test2.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: `df['Fruits'] = df[['Fruit1', 'Fruit2']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis=1)` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999163/15497888) everything else can stay the same.

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker